# amazon s3n integration with hadoop mapreduce not working

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, mapreduce, hdfs

I am trying to run some map reduce job over the files which are stored in amazon s3. I saw http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3 and following it to do the integration. Here is my code which sets the input directory for the map reduce job

```
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, "s3n://myAccessKey:mySecretKey@myS3Bucket/dir1/dir2/*.txt");
```

When i run the mapreduce job i am getting this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Wrong FS: s3n://myAccessKey:mySecretKey@myS3Bucket/dir1/dir2/*.txt,
 expected: s3n://myAccessKey:mySecretKey@myS3Bucket
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:381)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.makeQualified(FileSystem.java:294)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(FileInputFormat.java:352)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(FileInputFormat.java:321)
        at com.appdynamics.blitz.hadoop.migration.DataMigrationManager.convertAndLoadData(DataMigrationManager.java:340)
        at com.appdynamics.blitz.hadoop.migration.DataMigrationManager.migrateData(DataMigrationManager.java:300)
        at com.appdynamics.blitz.hadoop.migration.DataMigrationManager.migrate(DataMigrationManager.java:166)
        at com.appdynamics.blitz.command.DataMigrationCommand.run(DataMigrationCommand.java:53)
        at com.appdynamics.blitz.command.DataMigrationCommand.run(DataMigrationCommand.java:21)
        at com.yammer.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:58)
        at com.yammer.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:53)
        at com.yammer.dropwizard.Service.run(Service.java:61)
        at com.appdynamics.blitz.service.BlitzService.main(BlitzService.java:84)
```

I can't find resource to help me on this. Any pointer will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're just gonna have to keep playing with

> Wrong FS: s3n://myAccessKey:mySecretKey@myS3Bucket/dir1/dir2/*.txt

The path you're giving Hadoop just isn't correct and it won't work until it can access the correct files.

Answer (score 0):

So i found the problem. It was caused by this bug
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-3733

Even though i replaced the "/" by "%2F" it kept giving the same problem. I regenerated the keys and put one where is no "/" in the secret key and it fixed the issue.